# Vue.js / OpenSSL / Chrome: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: google-chrome, express, vue.js, openssl, self-signed

I am running a micro service (using `nginx`, `node.js`, `express`, `cors`, `https`). Then I am sending post requests to this micro service via a web front-end (using `vue.js` and `axios`), which gives me errors!

When using a tool like `Insomnia` or `Postman` everything works fine, when using Google Chrome with the front-end, I get the following error in Inspect -> Network -> Status:

```
(failed) net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I have generated the certificate with OpenSSL using SAN with proper DNS and IP, but it doesn't work with Google Chrome:

```
openssl req \                              
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -x509 \
    -nodes \
    -keyout server.key \
    -new \
    -out server.crt \
    -subj /CN=mydomainname \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -extensions SAN \
    -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:mydomainname,IP:123.123.123.123')) \
    -sha256 \
    -days 3650
```

What else can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this through another approach, where I wouldn't use OpenSSL but only nginx as a proxy server and certbots https certificates, which work fine with Google Chrome. Therefore I have configured multiple proxy passes in nginx, so all of the external requests were being passed via https and then being forwarded to the local servers appropriately:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```